# How can I fix the error #17 "The requested series type does not exist" error when trying to display a highcharts graph in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am trying to display a parliament (item) chart with highcharts, using the [basic example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parliament-chart) in their site.

In it, the very first configuration item says:

```
chart: {
      type: 'item'
},
```

And so this I use in my Vue.js project.

However, upon deploying I get an error in the console prompting to https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=item. There, the error message explains:

> The requested series type does not exist
>
> This error happens when setting `chart.type` or `series.type` to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that the module or extension where the series type is defined isn't included.
>
> For example in order to create an `arearange` series, the `highcharts-more.js` file must be loaded.

For this, I assume I am not importing the chart. However, how can I find out which one to import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it was in the API reference:

> [series.item](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.item)
>
> An `item` series. If the [type](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.item.type) option is not specified, it is inherited from [chart.type](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type).
>
> (...)
>
> Requires
>
> - [modules/item-series](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/item-series.js)

The hint of the module `item-series` helps us find the issue for Vue.js: it needs to `import item from 'highcharts/modules/item-series';` and then register it:

```
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
import highchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import item from 'highcharts/modules/item-series';

import Vue from "vue";


Vue.use(HighchartsVue);
item(Highcharts);
```

The same solution (with its corresponding module) should work for other graphs and you can find the list of all modules in https://code.highcharts.com/.

Comment: Right, some of the charts require an additional module to work - the API includes this information for each series type. List of the modules you can find here: https://code.highcharts.com/